# Can I define our company's business as sell furnishings if we do not sell furniture?

Tags: meaning, terminology, vocabulary, business-language, products

Our company produces and sells rugs, throw pillows, decorative objects, cushions, lamps, wall decor products, curtains, candle holders and generally everything else which is decorative for the house, but we don't sell any furnitures like beds, sofas, chairs and so on. Can I still define our company's business as sell furnishings?

Comment: In what context do you want to use it? A brochure, marketing, legal issues...

Answer (score 1):

You can't call it furnishing then. Furnishing includes furniture and tapestry only. You can rather use "home decor" to define your company!